# Fix values group by dates

Tags: python, pandas

```
            A         B        C    D
0  2002-01-13  15:00:00   Joseph  3.9
1  2002-01-13  15:00:00     Emma  1.9
2  2002-01-13  16:00:00   Joseph  8.0
3  2002-01-13  16:00:00     Emma  9.0
4  2002-01-13  17:00:00   Joseph  6.2
5  2002-01-13  17:00:00     Emma  4.5
6  2002-06-23  15:00:00   David   0.2   
7  2002-06-23  15:00:00   Rachel  6.7   
8  2002-06-23  16:00:00   David   6.6  
9  2002-06-23  16:00:00   Rachel  3.1   
10  2002-06-23  17:00:00  David   1.0  
11  2002-06-23  17:00:00  Rachel  3.2
```

I have a `df` group by times and dates.
I want to create a new column that fixes *D values* to *C names*, when *B = 15:00:00*.
It should be:

```
            A         B        C     D     E
0  2002-01-13  15:00:00   Joseph   3.9   3.9    # fix E value
1  2002-01-13  15:00:00     Emma   1.9   1.9    # fix E value
2  2002-01-13  16:00:00   Joseph   8.0   3.9    # Joseph 3.9 for A column
3  2002-01-13  16:00:00     Emma   9.0   1.9    # Emma 1.9 for A column
4  2002-01-13  17:00:00   Joseph   6.2   3.9
5  2002-01-13  17:00:00     Emma   4.5   1.9
6  2002-06-23  15:00:00    David   0.2   0.2    # fix E value
7  2002-06-23  15:00:00   Rachel   6.7   6.7    # fix E value
8  2002-06-23  16:00:00    David   6.6   0.2
9  2002-06-23  16:00:00   Rachel   3.1   6.7
10  2002-06-23  17:00:00   David   1.0   0.2
11  2002-06-23  17:00:00  Rachel   3.2   6.7
```

Comment: Note to downvoters: It's okay, this isn't a bad question. Most pandas questions don't involve code because code is useless. Quite often users try things that don't work. Posting attempts here is meaningless, data is more important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a `groupby` (on `C`) + `ffill` on a masked version of column `D`:

```
df['E'] = df.D.mask(df.B.ne('15:00:00')).groupby(df.C).ffill()
```

If `15:00:00` *isn't* the first timestamp in each group for `C`, then add a `bfill` call after -

```
df['E'] = df.D.mask(df.B.ne('15:00:00')).groupby(df.C).ffill().bfill()
```

```
df
             A         B       C    D    E
0   2002-01-13  15:00:00  Joseph  3.9  3.9
1   2002-01-13  15:00:00    Emma  1.9  1.9
2   2002-01-13  16:00:00  Joseph  8.0  3.9
3   2002-01-13  16:00:00    Emma  9.0  1.9
4   2002-01-13  17:00:00  Joseph  6.2  3.9
5   2002-01-13  17:00:00    Emma  4.5  1.9
6   2002-06-23  15:00:00   David  0.2  0.2
7   2002-06-23  15:00:00  Rachel  6.7  6.7
8   2002-06-23  16:00:00   David  6.6  0.2
9   2002-06-23  16:00:00  Rachel  3.1  6.7
10  2002-06-23  17:00:00   David  1.0  0.2
11  2002-06-23  17:00:00  Rachel  3.2  6.7
```

Comment: Way to figure out what OP meant. (-: